Katalon Is stopping due to opening of Google on same tab
In katalon when i execute any test suite it first open the Google in the same tab where katalon is present and now because in the tab where katalon was running now google is running so katalon stops working and we stop at google.com
i tried to use openWindow Command but ut did not work in that case also Google was opening and was stopped there, i changed some browser that supports extensions on mobile like lumor, wissi, and mask browser. It works on kiwi fine but from kiwi we can't open extension through katalon recorder so i need to use different browser
